# xml sitemap Error class PageContext in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xml-sitemap

I am making some site map for my site its is work correctly, but at now I have some problem in my sitemap

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.rosena.ir/sitemap.html</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-16</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.rosena.ir/sitemap_filter.xml?do=pro</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-16</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.rosena.ir/sitemap_filter.xml?do=cat</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-16</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.rosena.ir/sitemap_filter.xml?do=brand</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-16</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.rosena.ir/sitemap_filter.xml?do=en</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-16</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>https://www.rosena.ir/sitemap_filter.xml?do=ptag</loc>
<lastmod>2020-06-16</lastmod>
</sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

I get error:

> new (class PageContext { constructor(clientKey) { this.client = window[Symbol.for(clientKey)]; this.bindEvents(); } bindEvents() { const self = this; history.pushState = (f => function pushState() { const ret = f.apply(this, arguments); self.onUrlChange(); return ret; })(history.pushState); let firstReplaceEvent = true; history.replaceState = (f => function replaceState(params) { var ret = f.apply(this, arguments); if (!firstReplaceEvent) { self.onUrlChange(); } firstReplaceEvent = false; return ret; })(history.replaceState); window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () { self.onUrlChange(); }); } onUrlChange() { this.client.emitToBg('URLS_SAFE_CHECK__CONTENT_URL_REWRITED'); } })('MARIO_POST_CLIENT_eppiocemhmnlbhjplcgkofciiegomcon')

Comment: I'm having same issue with Sitemap. Any fixes found on this?

Comment: Any update on the fixes for this?

Comment: Please share more details, like the error you are facing. What you've posted looks like JS code - how is that related to the sitemap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, it was because of a `browser extension` (in my case Urban VPN).

The problem went away after **disabling the extension.**